# Function for rating songs in clementine

Tags: clementine

I can't find the function to rate songs in my clementine database, how can I make work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Right click on the track in Clementine and select *Edit*, move your mouse over the 5 stars of rating filling in as many stars as you want to rate it as then click to set. Then save the edit.
>
> Another method is to right click the column headers and select rating so it is visible. After that you can click on the stars directly to rate the track in the rating column.

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/5odh8b/how_can_i_rate_tracks_in_a_playlist_in_clementine/dcihzqu/)

Comment: second method made my day

Comment: and what about those many tracks where I cannot do this?
i tried to understand the logic behind but failed.
ID3v1 ID3v2 where are those rtings stored and why cant I do it on some tracks.
yes I know not on wav files... but mp3?

Comment: @U.V. further information about Clementine can be found [here.](https://www.clementine-player.org/) Since this answer is from 4 years ago, you may wish to ask a new question that includes the version of Clementine you are using and how you installed it, as well as the version of Ubuntu that you are using. A quick glance at the above link shows that for instance version 1.31 fixes a bug where ratings are deleted when upgrading from older versions. This may be related to your difficulty. It also looks like Clementine hasn't been addressed since this version change in 2016. Try rhythmbox?